# Google map api draggable marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here when I drag and drop marker. I write lat,lng coordinates created div. First no any div. When I drag and drop marker is created. I left marker where it writes lat,lng value to inside div. I drag and drop each time different a div is created. Divs have recenter class name. Later when I click a div. I can't get value of div. Also when I click a created div I want to move marker that lat,lng position. I hope I can explain my problem. You can look here http://jsfiddle.net/QvNUF/1015/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
Lat: <input type="text" id="lat"><br>
Lng: <input type="text" id="lng"><br>
<button id="selected">Selected Coordinates</button>
<button id="clear">Clear history</button>
<div id="results" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.015137,28.979530);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10, 
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), myOptions);
addMarker(myLatlng, 'Default Marker', map);
map.addListener('click',function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng, 'Click Generated Marker', map);
});
}
function addMarker(latlng,title,map) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: title,
        draggable:true
});
marker.addListener('drag',function(event) {
     $('#lat').val(event.latLng.lat())  ;
    $('#lng').val(event.latLng.lng())  ;
});
marker.addListener('dragend',function(event) {
    $('#lat').val(event.latLng.lat())  ;        
    $('#lng').val(event.latLng.lng())  ;
    var x=event.latLng.lat();
    var y=event.latLng.lng();
    $("#results").append('<div class="recenter">'+x+y+'</div>');
});
};  
    $('.recenter').click( function() {
        var a=$(this).text();
        alert(a);
    });
    $("#clear").click(function(){
        $("#results").text("");
        $("#results").hide();
    });
initialize();
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: try using marker.setPosition(latlng); onclick of the div

Comment: I used marker.setPosition(latlng); but it didn't work. I can't get value of div. When I drag and drop two times. 2 divs is created that has recenter name class. I have to give growing class name. For example recenter_1, recenter_2

Comment: Add onclick ="movemarker(x,y);" on evey div you append and then create function like function moveMarker(lat,lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)); 
  marker.setPosition(latlng);
}

Comment: You are right. But firstly when a div is created that has recenter classname. İt is writing lat, lng value of div. Later I have to use a function as your said.

Comment: I don't create just a div. Every drag and drop is created a div.

Comment: so what about the classname when you can add a function on click of every div ?? I think you got my point .. happy coding .. mark my comment as useful if it helped !

Comment: For example I drag and drop two times. Later two divs are created. Value of first div is 41.0617493982562728.924598359375068, value of second div is 41.0886659593529228.880653046875068. İf I use your function how can take lat lng from that values? Do you understand me?

Comment: check my answer, uncomment console.log and comment all other code and you will see the lat lng of clicked div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the click-listener for `.recenter` before the divs have been created, `click()` will not affect objects which haven't been created yet.

You may add the click-listener for the `<div/>`'s directly when you create them:

```
$("#results")
 .append($('<div>')
          .text(event.latLng.toUrlValue())
          .data('latlng',event.latLng)
          .click(function(){
                  marker.setPosition($(this).data('latlng'));
                 }));
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/QvNUF/1022/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/QvNUF/1022/)

Comment: I like this answer (y)

Comment: When I try this demo on my server I get an error. Cannot read property 'toUrlValue' of undefined. İs it an alternative this function?

Answer (score 1):

You need marker.setPosition(latlng)
Also you will have to decalre marker, map as globals above you code
yes , i checked your fiddle. I know your div structure ..just add `onclick ="movemarker(x,y);"` on div after class attribute and then

```
function moveMarker(lat,lng) { 
//console.log("lat:"+x+" lng:"+y);
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng)); marker.setPosition(latlng);
}
```